# Regex extraction on non-standard log

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm not sure it's possible but I've been trying to extract a piece of info from a non-standard log format.  The log could look as follows

```
field1:val1:extra1
val2:extra1
val3
```

So what I'm saying is val will always exist but field and extra won't.  I'm trying to come up with a regex that will always extract val regardless of the existence of field and extra.

The closest I've got is;

```
/[^:]*:?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[^:]):?/mg
```

But it's still not quite right.  Just to note val will not be a fixed length.  Neither will field nor extra.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?:([^:\r\n]+):(?=.*:))?([^:\r\n]+)(?::(.+))?
```

will match `field` always into group 1, `val` always into group 2, and `extra` always into group 3. In case `field` or `extra` do not exist, their groups will be empty.

Breakdown:

```
(?:               # begin non-capturing group
  ([^:\r\n]+)     #   group 1: any character except ":" or line-break, repeat
  :               #   a ":"
  (?=.*:)         #   must be followed by another ":" somewhere in the remaining string
)?                # end group, make optional
(                 # group 2
  [^:\r\n]+       #   any character except ":" or line-break, repeat
)                 # end group 2
(?:               # begin non-capturing group 
  :               #   a ":"
  (.+)            #   group 3: rest of the line
)?                # end group, make optional
```

The look-ahead `(?=.*:)` is the crucial part. It prevents the engine from matching `val` into group 1 in the `"val:extra"` case.

Note that if the group values can be empty, like so:

```
field1:val1:extra1
:val2:extra1
:val3:
```

then simply change the `+` to `*` in the capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks for the voodoo Tomalak.  Worked a treat!  Really appreciate the breakdown too.  (?= is lookahead right?.  Ahh just seen your edit re lookahead.  Cool.

Comment: Yes, it's the so-called "zero-width positive look-ahead assertion". Commonly called positive look-ahead. It makes sure a condition is true (in this case that `.*:` would match) without advancing the position of the regex engine in the string.

Comment: @Urbley: What if you have `field:val4`? Not sure this problem has a solution.

Comment: @Casimir Good question. Semantically this is indistinguishable from the `"val:extra"` case, at least without having any additional information, therefore the above expression would fill group 2 and 3 for that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you just use a branch reset group with all three possible alternatives capturing just the part you need into Group 1:

```
^(?|[^:]+:([^:]+):[^:]+|([^:]+):[^:]+|([^:]+))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uT1uS2/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?|` - branch reset group start (inner capturing group IDs will start from the same number)

  - `[^:]+:([^:]+):[^:]+` - 3 colon-separated parts, the mid one is captured into Group 1
  - `|` -  or
  - `([^:]+):[^:]+` - 2 colon-separated parts, the first one is captured into Group 1
  - `|` - or
  - `([^:]+) - Group 1 containing just 1 chunk of 1 or more chars other than`:`
- `)` - end of branch reset
- `$` - end of string.

Also, in case you need to get all the parts into the same capture group, I can suggest adding the `(?J)` *PCRE_INFO_JCHANGED* flag and use named capture groups:

```
(?J)^(?:(?<Field>[^:]+):(?<Val>[^:]+):(?<Extra>[^:]+)|(?<Val>[^:]+):(?<Extra>[^:]+)|(?<Val>[^:]+))$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX9bM2/1)

Comment: Also nice. Just for the OP's reference: [regular-expressions.info on Branch Reset Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html)

Comment: Yes, also [here is a good explanation](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#branchreset).